# How to read result TAG out of below dynamic string in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Given the following string:

```
a:3:{s:6:"status";i:1;s:3:"msg";s:39:"Transaction has been already Completed.";s:6:"result";s:1620:"eyJtaWhwYXlpZCI6NDAzOTkzNzE1NTExODQwODY3LCJ tb2RlIjoiREJRUiIsInN0YXR1cyI6ImZhaWx1cmUiLCJrZXkiOiI3a2h6VEciLCJ0eG5pZCI6IjEy MzQ1IiwiYW1vdW50IjoiMS4wMCIsImFkZGVkb24iOiIyMDE5LTA1LTE3IDE3OjEwOjEzIiwic HJvZHVjdGluZm8iOiJPZmZsaW5lIER5bmFtaWMgUVIiLCJmaXJzdG5hbWUiOiIiLCJsYXN0 bmFtZSI6IiIsImFkZHJlc3MxIjoiIiwiYWRkcmVzczIiOiIiLCJjaXR5IjoiIiwic3RhdGUiOiIiLCJjb3V udHJ5IjoiIiwiemlwY29kZSI6IiIsImVtYWlsIjoiIiwicGhvbmUiOiIiLCJ1ZGYxIjoiIiwidWRmMiI6IiIsI nVkZjMiOiIiLCJ1ZGY0IjoiIiwidWRmNSI6IiIsInVkZjYiOiIiLCJ1ZGY3IjoiIiwidWRmOCI6IiIsInVk ZjkiOiIiLCJ1ZGYxMCI6IiIsImNhcmRfdG9rZW4iOiIiLCJjYXJkX25vIjoiNDc5OTQ3WFhYWFh YMjU2MyIsImZpZWxkMCI6IkRZUTEyMzQ1NjU4NDA0IiwiZmllbGQxIjoiNFZJU0FWSVNBVk lTQVZJMCIsImZpZWxkMiI6IjNWMDM2MyIsImZpZWxkMyI6IjE4MTMwMDA4MDIwOTEiLCJ maWVsZDQiOiIiLCJmaWVsZDUiOiJ5ZWxsb3dxci5wYXl1dGVzdGR5bmFtaWNxckBoZGZjY mFuayFwYXl1dGVzdGR5bmFtaWNxciFOQSIsImZpZWxkNiI6IktvdGFrIE1haGluZHJhIEJhb mshOTExMjEyNDE4NSFLS0JLMDAwMDI1NSE5MTc4MjcwNTc2MDQiLCJmaWVsZDciOiJ UcmFuc2FjdGlvbiBzdWNjZXNzIiwiZmllbGQ4IjoiIiwiZmllbGQ5IjoiU1VDQ0VTU3xDb21wbGV 0ZWQgVXNpbmcgQ2FsbGJhY2siLCJwYXltZW50X3NvdXJjZSI6InBheXUiLCJQR19UWVBF IjoiQlFSIiwiZXJyb3IiOiJFMDAwIiwiZXJyb3JfTWVzc2FnZSI6Ik5vIEVycm9yIiwibmV0X2Ftb3V udF9kZWJpdCI6MCwidW5tYXBwZWRzdGF0dXMiOiJkcm9wcGVkIiwiaGFzaCI6IjgxMWI0N TE2ODdhYzE5NjYwMTk4MjVjYjgzMjMzMGMyNzMyNjk5MTI0YzI4MWU5NGJlMDE1ODJh OTRiMzc5OWJkMjYyNWZlY2Y2NzViNDA4ZWUzZDk1ZTU4NzZmZTgyNWFmMDJlMGNh M2IzNGRlMDY1NzViMDJmMDgxZjg0OTllIiwiYmFua19yZWZfbm8iOiI5MTM3Mzk5NTMyMT YiLCJiYW5rX3JlZl9udW0iOiI5MTM3Mzk5NTMyMTYiLCJiYW5rY29kZSI6IlVQSUJRUiIsInN1 cmwiOm51bGwsImN1cmwiOm51bGwsImZ1cmwiOm51bGwsIm1lQ29kZSI6IntcInBnTWVyY 2hhbnRJZFwiOlwiSERGQzAwMDAwMDA2MTg5OFwifSJ9";}
```

I would like to retrieve the following string, which appears in the `s:1620:` field:

```
"eyJtaWhwYXlpZCI6NDAzOTkzNzE1NTExODQwODY3LCJ tb2RlIjoiREJRUiIsInN0YXR1cyI6ImZhaWx1cmUiLCJrZXkiOiI3a2h6VEciLCJ0eG5pZCI6IjEy MzQ1IiwiYW1vdW50IjoiMS4wMCIsImFkZGVkb24iOiIyMDE5LTA1LTE3IDE3OjEwOjEzIiwic HJvZHVjdGluZm8iOiJPZmZsaW5lIER5bmFtaWMgUVIiLCJmaXJzdG5hbWUiOiIiLCJsYXN0 bmFtZSI6IiIsImFkZHJlc3MxIjoiIiwiYWRkcmVzczIiOiIiLCJjaXR5IjoiIiwic3RhdGUiOiIiLCJjb3V udHJ5IjoiIiwiemlwY29kZSI6IiIsImVtYWlsIjoiIiwicGhvbmUiOiIiLCJ1ZGYxIjoiIiwidWRmMiI6IiIsI nVkZjMiOiIiLCJ1ZGY0IjoiIiwidWRmNSI6IiIsInVkZjYiOiIiLCJ1ZGY3IjoiIiwidWRmOCI6IiIsInVk ZjkiOiIiLCJ1ZGYxMCI6IiIsImNhcmRfdG9rZW4iOiIiLCJjYXJkX25vIjoiNDc5OTQ3WFhYWFh YMjU2MyIsImZpZWxkMCI6IkRZUTEyMzQ1NjU4NDA0IiwiZmllbGQxIjoiNFZJU0FWSVNBVk lTQVZJMCIsImZpZWxkMiI6IjNWMDM2MyIsImZpZWxkMyI6IjE4MTMwMDA4MDIwOTEiLCJ maWVsZDQiOiIiLCJmaWVsZDUiOiJ5ZWxsb3dxci5wYXl1dGVzdGR5bmFtaWNxckBoZGZjY mFuayFwYXl1dGVzdGR5bmFtaWNxciFOQSIsImZpZWxkNiI6IktvdGFrIE1haGluZHJhIEJhb mshOTExMjEyNDE4NSFLS0JLMDAwMDI1NSE5MTc4MjcwNTc2MDQiLCJmaWVsZDciOiJ UcmFuc2FjdGlvbiBzdWNjZXNzIiwiZmllbGQ4IjoiIiwiZmllbGQ5IjoiU1VDQ0VTU3xDb21wbGV 0ZWQgVXNpbmcgQ2FsbGJhY2siLCJwYXltZW50X3NvdXJjZSI6InBheXUiLCJQR19UWVBF IjoiQlFSIiwiZXJyb3IiOiJFMDAwIiwiZXJyb3JfTWVzc2FnZSI6Ik5vIEVycm9yIiwibmV0X2Ftb3V udF9kZWJpdCI6MCwidW5tYXBwZWRzdGF0dXMiOiJkcm9wcGVkIiwiaGFzaCI6IjgxMWI0N TE2ODdhYzE5NjYwMTk4MjVjYjgzMjMzMGMyNzMyNjk5MTI0YzI4MWU5NGJlMDE1ODJh OTRiMzc5OWJkMjYyNWZlY2Y2NzViNDA4ZWUzZDk1ZTU4NzZmZTgyNWFmMDJlMGNh M2IzNGRlMDY1NzViMDJmMDgxZjg0OTllIiwiYmFua19yZWZfbm8iOiI5MTM3Mzk5NTMyMT YiLCJiYW5rX3JlZl9udW0iOiI5MTM3Mzk5NTMyMTYiLCJiYW5rY29kZSI6IlVQSUJRUiIsInN1 cmwiOm51bGwsImN1cmwiOm51bGwsImZ1cmwiOm51bGwsIm1lQ29kZSI6IntcInBnTWVyY 2hhbnRJZFwiOlwiSERGQzAwMDAwMDA2MTg5OFwifSJ9"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pattern = @"\{(?'bracket'.*)\}";
            string input = "a:3:{s:6:\"status\";i:1;s:3:\"msg\";s:39:\"Transaction has been already Completed.\";s:6:\"result\";s:1620:\"eyJtaWhwYXlpZCI6NDAzOTkzNzE1NTExODQwODY3LCJ tb2RlIjoiREJRUiIsInN0YXR1cyI6ImZhaWx1cmUiLCJrZXkiOiI3a2h6VEciLCJ0eG5pZCI6IjEy MzQ1IiwiYW1vdW50IjoiMS4wMCIsImFkZGVkb24iOiIyMDE5LTA1LTE3IDE3OjEwOjEzIiwic HJvZHVjdGluZm8iOiJPZmZsaW5lIER5bmFtaWMgUVIiLCJmaXJzdG5hbWUiOiIiLCJsYXN0 bmFtZSI6IiIsImFkZHJlc3MxIjoiIiwiYWRkcmVzczIiOiIiLCJjaXR5IjoiIiwic3RhdGUiOiIiLCJjb3V udHJ5IjoiIiwiemlwY29kZSI6IiIsImVtYWlsIjoiIiwicGhvbmUiOiIiLCJ1ZGYxIjoiIiwidWRmMiI6IiIsI nVkZjMiOiIiLCJ1ZGY0IjoiIiwidWRmNSI6IiIsInVkZjYiOiIiLCJ1ZGY3IjoiIiwidWRmOCI6IiIsInVk ZjkiOiIiLCJ1ZGYxMCI6IiIsImNhcmRfdG9rZW4iOiIiLCJjYXJkX25vIjoiNDc5OTQ3WFhYWFh YMjU2MyIsImZpZWxkMCI6IkRZUTEyMzQ1NjU4NDA0IiwiZmllbGQxIjoiNFZJU0FWSVNBVk lTQVZJMCIsImZpZWxkMiI6IjNWMDM2MyIsImZpZWxkMyI6IjE4MTMwMDA4MDIwOTEiLCJ maWVsZDQiOiIiLCJmaWVsZDUiOiJ5ZWxsb3dxci5wYXl1dGVzdGR5bmFtaWNxckBoZGZjY mFuayFwYXl1dGVzdGR5bmFtaWNxciFOQSIsImZpZWxkNiI6IktvdGFrIE1haGluZHJhIEJhb mshOTExMjEyNDE4NSFLS0JLMDAwMDI1NSE5MTc4MjcwNTc2MDQiLCJmaWVsZDciOiJ UcmFuc2FjdGlvbiBzdWNjZXNzIiwiZmllbGQ4IjoiIiwiZmllbGQ5IjoiU1VDQ0VTU3xDb21wbGV 0ZWQgVXNpbmcgQ2FsbGJhY2siLCJwYXltZW50X3NvdXJjZSI6InBheXUiLCJQR19UWVBF IjoiQlFSIiwiZXJyb3IiOiJFMDAwIiwiZXJyb3JfTWVzc2FnZSI6Ik5vIEVycm9yIiwibmV0X2Ftb3V udF9kZWJpdCI6MCwidW5tYXBwZWRzdGF0dXMiOiJkcm9wcGVkIiwiaGFzaCI6IjgxMWI0N TE2ODdhYzE5NjYwMTk4MjVjYjgzMjMzMGMyNzMyNjk5MTI0YzI4MWU5NGJlMDE1ODJh OTRiMzc5OWJkMjYyNWZlY2Y2NzViNDA4ZWUzZDk1ZTU4NzZmZTgyNWFmMDJlMGNh M2IzNGRlMDY1NzViMDJmMDgxZjg0OTllIiwiYmFua19yZWZfbm8iOiI5MTM3Mzk5NTMyMT YiLCJiYW5rX3JlZl9udW0iOiI5MTM3Mzk5NTMyMTYiLCJiYW5rY29kZSI6IlVQSUJRUiIsInN1 cmwiOm51bGwsImN1cmwiOm51bGwsImZ1cmwiOm51bGwsIm1lQ29kZSI6IntcInBnTWVyY 2hhbnRJZFwiOlwiSERGQzAwMDAwMDA2MTg5OFwifSJ9\";}";
            string insideBrackets = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups["bracket"].Value;
            string[] messages = insideBrackets.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();
            string output = messages.Where(x => x.StartsWith("s:1620:")).First();
        }


    }

}
```